# Why is this JQuery Script no longer working on my https Server?

Tags: jquery, tumblr

I have this old jquery script to display Tumblr posts on a web site.
The script works well for me on my lokal server. I even believe it was working well on http, but I'm not certain. Yet, on https, the script is no longer working.
What could be the reason for this?

THis is the script:

```
/**
 * jquery.tumblr.js - jQuery plugin for embedding tumblr posts
 *
 * https://github.com/bicknoyle/jquery.tumblr
 * Copyright (c) 2012 Nick Boyle
 * MIT Licensed
 */
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.tumblr = function(o)
    {
        var s = $.extend({
            append: false,          // [bool] Append to target container, instead of clearing first
            hostname: null,         // [string] The hostname of your blog (ex: myblog.tumblr.com)
            options: { },           // [object] key:val of options to pass the tumblr API, see http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v1#api_read for details
            template:'{body}',      // [string or function] template used to construct each post <li> - see code for available {vars}
            type_templates: { }     // [string or function] see below for defaults
        }, o);

        // [string or function] template to be used for each type; these defaults are based on the markup used by the default tumblr theme
        var default_type_templates = {
            answer:'<div class="question">{question}</div><div class="copy">{answer}</div>',
            audio: '<div class="audio">{audio_player}</div><div class="copy"></div>',
            chat:  function(item) {
              str = '<div class="title">{conversation_title}</div><div class="chat"><div class="lines">';
              for(i in item.conversation) { str = str+'<div class="line"><strong>'+item.conversation[i].label+'</strong>'+item.conversation[i].phrase+'</div>' };
              return str+'</div></div>';
            },
            link:  function(item) {
              if( item.link_text ) { return '<div class="link"><a href="{link_url}" target="_blank">{link_text}</a></div><div class="copy">{link_description}</div>' };
              return '<div class="link"><a href="{link_url}" target="_blank">{link_url}</a></div><div class="copy">{link_description}</div>'
            },
            quote:   '<div class="quote">{quote_text}</div><div class="copy">{quote_source}</div>',
            photo:   '<div class="media"><img src="{photo_url_500}" alt="" /></div><div class="copy">{photo_caption}</div>',
            text:    '<div class="title">{regular_title}</div><div class="copy">{regular_body}</div>',
            video:   '<div class="media">{video_player_500}</div><div class="copy">{video_caption}</div>'
        };
        s.type_templates = $.extend(default_type_templates, s.type_templates);

        function extract_relative_time(date)
        {
            var toInt = function(val) { return parseInt(val, 10); };
            var relative_to = new Date();
            var delta = toInt((relative_to.getTime() - date) / 1000);
            if (delta < 1) delta = 0;
            return {
              days:    toInt(delta / 86400),
              hours:   toInt(delta / 3600),
              minutes: toInt(delta / 60),
              seconds: toInt(delta)
            };
        }

        function format_relative_time(time_ago)
        {
            if ( time_ago.days > 2 )     return 'about ' + time_ago.days + ' days ago';
            if ( time_ago.hours > 24 )   return 'about a day ago';
            if ( time_ago.hours > 2 )    return 'about ' + time_ago.hours + ' hours ago';
            if ( time_ago.minutes > 45 ) return 'about an hour ago';
            if ( time_ago.minutes > 2 )  return 'about ' + time_ago.minutes + ' minutes ago';
            if ( time_ago.seconds > 1 )  return 'about ' + time_ago.seconds + ' seconds ago';
            return 'just now';
        }

        /**
         * Prepare the data for each posts, for use by the user in the template
         */
        function prepare_template_data(item)
        {
            var o = {};

            /**
             * Change keys from two-words to two_words
             */
            var key_regex = new RegExp('-','g');
            $.each(item, function(key,val) {
                o[key.replace(key_regex, '_')] = val;
            });

            // "text" is referred to by API output as "regular"????
            if( item.type == 'regular' ) { o.type = 'text'; }
            // "chat" is referred to by API output as "conversation"????
            if( item.type == 'conversation' ) { o.type = 'chat'; }

            /**
             * Add some custom vars that may be handy for the user
             */
            o.relative_time = format_relative_time(extract_relative_time(Date.parse(o.date)));
            o.reblog_url = 'http://www.tumblr.com/reblog/'+o.id+'/'+o.reblog_key;

            /**
             * Create body, based on the type_template for that
             * media type.
             */
            o.body = t(s.type_templates[o.type], o);
            return o;
        }

        // Expand values inside simple string templates with {placeholders}
        function t(template, info) {
            var result;
            if ( typeof template === 'string' || typeof template === 'number' ) {
                result = template;
            }
            else {
                result = template(info);
            }


            $.each(info, function(key, val) {
                result = result.replace(new RegExp('{'+key+'}','g'), val === null ? '' : val);
            });
            return result;
        }
        // Export the t function for use when passing a function as the 'template' option
        $.extend({tumblr: {t: t}});

        /**
         * Get data from tumblr, listify it, and load it into the widget
         */
        var target_selector = this;
        $.getJSON('http://'+s.hostname+'/api/read/json?callback=?', s.options, function(response) {
            var list = $('<ul class="post_list">');
            var posts = $.map(response.posts, prepare_template_data);
            //posts = $.grep(posts, s.filter).sort(s.comparator).slice(0, s.count);//TODO: Implement
            list.append($.map(posts, function(o) { return '<li>' + t(s.template, o) + '</li>'; }).join('')).
              children('li:first').addClass('post_first').end().
              children('li:odd').addClass('post_even').end().
              children('li:even').addClass('post_odd');
            if( !s.append ) {
                target_selector.empty()
            }
            target_selector.append(list).trigger('tumblr:load');
        });
        return target_selector;
    }
})( jQuery );
```

I am grateful about all of your comments!
Felix

Comment: A while back tumblr stopped allowing updates to themes that still had http resources in, you need to access everything via https, I think for most stuff it's fine as the rest of the world has moved over to https pretty much. Often just putting the s after http confirms that the resource is available, otherwise just stick the code in your template. You can minify it using https://javascript-minifier.com/ or similar, it's only 130 odd lines of code uncompressed so not a big issue.

Comment: Actually looking at this again, there might be a fix, it would be useful if you can verify that it works in any environment, also there should be some console error about trying to cross different protocols, I will try and write something that should give a possible answer, at least something to try out.

Comment: Hello Iharby, thanks for replying. What do you mean by "that it works in ANY ENVIRONMENT"? How can I test this? The file I am trying to get to run can be found here: https://github.com/alexhayes/jquery-tumblr

Comment: Sorry I meant protocol rather than environment. In your question you write 'The script works well for me on my local server. I even believe it was working well on http,' so I assume it works over one protocol?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure if this will work but you could try using the same protocol depending on what server you are on (localhost, https etc)

Instead of this:

```
$.getJSON('http://'+s.hostname+'/api/read/json?callback=?', s.options, function(response) {
```

What about

```
var protocol = document.location.protocol;
$.getJSON(protocol + s.hostname+'/api/read/json?callback=?', s.options, function(response) {
```

This should mean if your code is running in localhost the protocol will be `http`, but if you are running on a secure server, then the protocol will be `https`.

The issue might be that you cannot make the request via http at all, I don't know 100%, so you will need to test this out.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, when I change the code, the screen stays blank.

Comment: In case you wanted to have a look at the code - this is the exact same script which just won't run on my server, any more: https://github.com/alexhayes/jquery-tumblr

Comment: I am going to post another answer, I suspect that the code this is based on is quite old.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after downloading the github repo code I have made a working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/2dxcL536/

I have included the `jquery.tumblr.js` at the top of the script window, right at the bottom is the actual function call.

I have changed this call to `https` and now at least the function is making the api call (incidentally in localhost this does work with just http)

```
$('#posts')
    .tumblr({
    url:        'https://blog.thehiddenventure.com', // was previously http
    pagination: '#pagination',
    loading:    '#loading'
});
```

However there seems to be some other error with the code.

If you run it and open the network panel you can see the items being retrieved from the call.

[image]

And here is the json response: https://blog.thehiddenventure.com/api/read/json?start=0&num=20&_=1613389676379 this means it should be possible to build the code from this response (which is what this library is meant to do, but as I say I think it is outdated). You could roll your own potentially.

**UPDATE**
OK the error was being thrown by a function called timeago, so I have set this to false, it is now outputting data in the jsfiddle (although there are other errors in the console).

Change

```
'timeago'            : false,
```

In `jquery.tumblr.js`